# Java run ONLY certain signed applets

Tags: security, java

Regarding the Java 0-day exploit I'd like to configure the Java Runtime such that it only executes signed applets, preferably such that I either

- define a whilelist of certificates I allow
- define allowed root certificates
- prevent at least unsigned/untrusted applets from starting at all

How can I configure that?

Thanks

Marki

Comment: Have you considered just disabling Java in your browser completely?

Comment: @DanielBeck: It's not always an option, unfortunately.

Comment: @grawity Yes, but if Java isn't required for particular applications or uses, it's the best option.

Comment: Opera will let you disable Java, but enable it on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Java IS required on the internal network for some apps. I don't want it to run stuff from the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is mostly not impossible but very difficult as you have to modify the used JRE.

Therefore an easier approach is to use Java only on Internet pages you trust. This can be done e.g. in Firefox in combination with NoScript add-on. NoScript disables by default all plugins - they are only shown if the users enables the domain temporary or permanent.

Comment: The problem with NoScript is that it disables JavaSCRIPT together with the rest. I don't want to lose Javascript. I want to disable Java on SOME sites. By site, by certificate or whatever. Doing that seems to be an impossible task.

Comment: In the default configuration, yes. But you can configure NoScript to block only plugin objects.

Comment: Ok, and how? I've seen this forum post: http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=9502 However it doesn't seem to really work for everyone.

Comment: In the configuration enable scripts globally and only disable the Java plugin.

Comment: Didn't I say that it needs to work for *some* sites?

Comment: I was talking about the base configuration. Furthermore you can disable NoScript completely for selected sites. Hence you have JavaScript working on all sites and Java working only on selective sites. Didi I miss anything?

Comment: Well, yeah, actual instructions on how to really accomplish that using NoScript.